# Ionic application framework Installation in centos server

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to build ionic project in centos server. while building the ionic in centos server, I am getting the below error.

```
[root@localhost todo]# ionic build android
Native thread-sleep not available.
This will result in much slower performance, but it will still work.
You should re-install spawn-sync or upgrade to the lastest version of node if possible.
Check /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/cross-spawn/node_modules/spawn-sync/error.log for more details
Running command: /root/todo/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /root/todo
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: /root/todo/platforms/android/cordova/build
[Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /root/todo/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /root/todo/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2


[root@localhost todo]# npm -v
1.3.6
[root@localhost todo]# cordova -v
5.4.1
[root@localhost todo]# ionic -v
1.7.12
```

i have sucessfully installed all the packages for centos server .

```
[root@localhost todo]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-504.el6.i686 #1 SMP Wed Oct 15 03:02:07 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

i have used the following steps.

1. `yum install nodejs`
2. `npm install -g cordova ionic`
3. `ionic start todo blank`
4. `cd todo && ls`
5. `ionic platform add android`
6. `ionic build android` ( getting error in centos linux server)

For these steps, i have already pasted the above error.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the Android SDK and add the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable.

Steps from [spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/gs/android/):

1. From the [Android web site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), download the correct version of the Android SDK for your operating system.
2. Unzip the archive to a location of your choosing. For example, on Linux or Mac, you can place it in the root of your user directory. See the [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html) web site for additional installation details.
3. Configure the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable based on the location of the Android SDK. Additionally, consider adding `ANDROID_HOME/tools`, and `ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools` to your PATH.

   ```
   export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/android-sdk-linux
   export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
   ```

The Android SDK download does not include specific Android platforms. To run the code in this guide, you need to download and install the latest SDK platform. You do this by using the Android SDK and AVD Manager that you installed in the previous section.

1. Open the **Android SDK Manager** window:

   ```
   android
   ```

   **Note**: If this command does not open the **Android SDK Manager**, then your path is not configured correctly.
2. Select the **Tools** checkbox.
3. Select the checkbox for the **latest Android SDK**.
4. From the **Extras** folder, select the checkbox for the **Android Support Library**.
5. Click the **Install packages…**​ button to complete the download and installation.

   **Note**: 
   You may want to install all the available updates, but be aware it will take longer, as each API level is a large download.

Comment: hi david i have installed the sdk in server , while during build i am getting the below error.